# Предложенная правка автоматически отклоняется, если кто-то изменил описание метки

Tags: обсуждение, дефект, поддержка, очередь-проверок, предлагаемые-правки

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/333189

1. Было предложено описание метки.
2. Оно было одобрено одним пользователем.
3. На странице метки https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tags/astra-linux/info **кнопка редактирования описания недоступна**. Но можно зайти в историю описания и там нажать **править**:

   > [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Поправить описание метки.
5. Изначально предложенная правка автоматически отклоняется с причиной "Правка конфликтует с последующей правкой".

Если это нормальное поведение, то весьма не очевидное. Для меня это выглядит как баг.